# find max of a function that is minimized of a group of functions

Tags: algorithm

I want to find an algorithm that find the max of a function which is minimized of a group of other functions. The problem can be described as follow:
Find max of `F(x)`. `F(x) = min (f1(x), f2(x), ..., fn(x))` with `a <= x <= b`.

Comment: Where does `a` and `b` come into play?

Comment: Is there any additional information about f1..fn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic maximin problem, commonly used in tree searching to prune sub-trees.

In a maximin, the "current max" is kept.  Then, for each iteration of x, loop through f(1->n).  If any fn comes up with a value < the current max, there is no point to continue (as the minimum of all the functions will definitely be <= this value).  Therefore, stop and go for another iteration of x.

Without knowing the fn functions, there is no analytical method to get the answer without iteration.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the "safety place" problem in facebook hacker cup http://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php/?round=188859297819219 . The function is the distance between two points in 3D space. Can we use a analytical method for improving the iteration?

Comment: Might.  If you know that they are all distance functions, you can prune a lot of the search tree.  For example, once you have a distance, any point with one axis further than this distance is automatically impossible to be the minimum, so you can skip it.  Triangle inequality stuff.]

Comment: For certain problems, you can use Newton's method to jump large distances and converge to a solution earlier.  However, I am not sure a maximin of distance functions can be solved that way -- you may miss some solutions which are localized minmia.

Comment: Many maximin or minimax problems are NP-Complete or worse.  For example, chess is a maximin/minimax problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
def F(x):
   return min(f1(x),f2(x),f3(x),f4(x),f5(x))

max(F(x) for x in xrange(a,b+1))
```

Comment: Thanks, however I want to study an algorithm, not a built in function.

Comment: @coolkid: Just create a min function that takes an array as its argument (i.e. finds the min of an array). Use the same idea to create a function for max. That's all that is needed.